# Content switch not working like it is supposed to work

Tags: javascript, css

I found a content switch code online. It works great until I add my search box code then none of it works. I am trying to get each search to replace the other one when you click on a different search engine. The bottom one replaces each other but they are supposed to replace the google one that is there at first but dont. Im sure there is probably a much easier way to do this but I am a very new coder and this is beyond what I know what to do.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```css
/**************************************************************************************************************************************************Search Bar*/
form {
display: flex;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}   
    
.BorderLineSearch {
align-items: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 5px 15px;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.BorderLineSearch img {
height: 27px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.BorderLineSearch:hover, .BorderLineSearch:focus {
background-color: transparent;
}

.BorderLineSearch input {
appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;  
border: 0;  
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 300;   
-moz-appearance: none;  
outline: 0; 
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 800px;   
}

.BorderLineSearch button {
appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;  
border: 0;
color: #aaaaaa!important;   
-moz-appearance: none;  
outline: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

.BorderLineSearch button:hover {
appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;  
border: 0;
color: #aaaaaa!important;   
-moz-appearance: none;  
outline: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

.BorderLineSearch button:focus {
appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;  
border: 0;
color: #aaaaaa!important;   
-moz-appearance: none;  
outline: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

/************************************************************************************************************************************************Place Holder*/
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
color: #aaaaaa;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
color: #aaaaaa;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
opacity: 1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
color: #aaaaaa;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
}

/******************************************************************************************************************************************************Middle*/
.middle {
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid green;
border-radius: 0px;
bottom: 0;
height: 275px;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 650px;
}

.collapse{
background: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
display: block; 
}

.collapse + input{
display: none; /* hide the checkboxes */
}

.collapse + input + div{
display:none;
}

.collapse + input:checked + div{
display:block;
}

.dropbtn {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: none;
color: #aaaaaa;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
padding: 0px; 
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
position: relative; 
}

.dropdown-content {
background-color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
display: none;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
display: block;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none; 
}

.dropdown a:hover {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

.show {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
<div class="dropdown">
<div><div class="BorderLineSearch">
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search?q=">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/g-favicon.ico"><buttons onclick="myFunction()"class="dropbtn">jhj</buttons>
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder=" Search the Web..." autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="button"><font size="4"><i class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></font></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#google"><label class="collapse" for="_1">google</label></a>
<a href="#duck"><label class="collapse" for="_3">duck</label></a>
<a href="#bing"><label class="collapse" for="_4">bing</label></a>
<a href="#yahoo"><label class="collapse" for="_2">yahoo</label></a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="google">
<label class="collapse" for="_1"></label>
<input id="_1" type="radio" name="c1"> 
<div><div class="BorderLineSearch">
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search?q=">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/g-favicon.ico"><buttons onclick="myFunction()"class="dropbtn">jhj</buttons>
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder=" Search the Web..." autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="button"><font size="4"><i class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></font></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="yahoo">
<label class="collapse" for="_2"></label>
<input id="_2" type="radio" name="c1">
<div><div class="BorderLineSearch">
<form method="get" action="http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/yayoo.png"><buttons onclick="myFunction()"class="dropbtn">jhj</buttons>
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder=" Search the Web..." autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="button"><font size="4"><i class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></font></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="duck">
<label class="collapse" for="_3"></label>
<input id="_3" type="radio" name="c1">
<div><div class="BorderLineSearch">
<form method="get" action="http://duckduckgo.com/?q=">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/duck.png"><buttons onclick="myFunction()"class="dropbtn">jhj</buttons>
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder=" Search the Web..." autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="button"><font size="4"><i class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></font></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="bing">
<label class="collapse" for="_4"></label>
<input id="_4" type="radio" name="c1">
<div><div class="BorderLineSearch">
<form method="get" action="http://www.bing.com/search?q=">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/bing.png"><buttons onclick="myFunction()"class="dropbtn">jhj</buttons>
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder=" Search the Web..." autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="button"><font size="4"><i class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></font></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Please if anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.